# Blinding Flash - how long does the missed attacks from elites last?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

The damage reduction this skill has (30% chance to miss from elite) - is that only for the 3 seconds or does it last until the monster or you die (like when you die they reset hp and probably any curses)

And please confirm - elites includes champions (blue packs) and unique (yellow)... not include bosses like butcher or the purple ones etc... right?

Comment: I beleive the 30% miss chance only lasts for the 3 seconds the blind lasts on other eamies, but haven't tested, so not 100% sure.

Comment: Elites includes any rare/unique/superunique enemy, including bosses, champions, uniques, etc

Comment: Also, to get your nomenclature right :
- Champions are blue
- Rares are yellow
- Uniques and Bosses are Purple

Answer (score 1):

Missed attacks and damage reduction last 3 seconds - the length of the skill.

Elites include all special enemies - Any enemy whose name isn't white is considered an elite. The community has generally summed up elites to mean this. Bosses are called bosses to differentiate them being an act-ending elite.

Comment: do elites still have the built in cc reduction that they used to have pre 2.0?

Comment: @z' You get diminishing returns on cc. You'll notice that you can't knockup heavy elites or cc any act-ending boss. Here is a forum post that also links to the developer blog about elite cc http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/11883238503